Can't find "Manage Schemes" on XCode 15.4
On Previous XCode versions, we had the "Manage Schemes" option under the submenu of the target button. but on the new XCode sometimes it's gone!
Where can I find it?!


You can find it here:
Product => Scheme => manage Schemas...

